# Regarding SharePoint and Excel file with VBA/Macro (Excel Web Services)

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to Excel Web Services in SharePoint..

I created an excel sheet with calculated column. Uploaded the doc to SharePoint. Added the doc on web part page  along with a choice filter web part. The calculated column updates it self based on the value passed to other cell by the filter web part.

Then, I created another excel sheet with vba code/macro. It is supposed to filter the excel table based on value entered in say col4+row1. This works in excel. Uploaded the doc to SharePoint. Added the doc on web part page along with a choice filter web part. The value gets passed to col4+row1. However, code that filters the sheet wont run in SharePoint!

Is it true that SharePoint does not support vba/macros? If so, is there any other alternative to achieve filtering functionality of excel sheet in SharePoint?

**UPDATE 1:**
I am doing some research on SQL Server Analysis Services and DAX, here is a [tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2000/sql-server-analysis-services-ssas/). I do not know if this can be used in SharePoint, but I will try this way..

Comment: Yes, SharePoint does not execute macros - you can upload them just fine, but it doesn't execute them. Have you considered adding SharePoint metadata for filtering?

Comment: Can you point me to some reference links to try this, please...

Comment: Go to your list settings, add a few columns and filter by these. There is no easy out of the box solution which fills these based upon some value **within** your Execl files.

Comment: OK, I am looking for solution based on excel and not the list based filtering! This is because we already have excel files that need to go on the server and we need to use excel web service in SharePoint. I know that there is no easy solution and that's the reason I have come to this forum to get pointers to what the possible solutions are..

Answer (score -2):

try fillter and then your done. Easy as pie!

Comment: Please, add some informative answers, with some background knowledge.

Comment: This isn't very helpful to the OP. Please give information regarding the solution to the OP's problem.